# Request tracker v4 in CentOS 6.2 returned 74

Tags: centos, request-tracker, msmtp

I have installed the RT v4 in CentOS
and I have this message:

```
Nov 11 20:57:54 ticket RTmailer: CALL msmtp -nt -oi -t RETURNED 74
```

If I run "msmpt" command from the shell it works fine.

/opt/rt4/etc/msmtp_wrapper

```
/usr/bin/msmtp -t -C /etc/msmtprc
/usr/bin/logger -t RTmailer -p syslog.info -- CALL msmtp -nt "$@" RETURNED $?
```

RT_SiteConfig.pm

```
Set( $SendmailPath, "/opt/rt4/etc/msmtp_wrapper");
```

I have no idea about this behavior. I use external smtp server. How can i tune RT for it?

Thanks for the help.

PS.If you need more technical information i can upd the question.